# How can I optimize a collision engine where order is significant and collision is conditional based on object group?

Tags: c++, collision-detection, performance, optimization, grid

**If this is your first time on this question, I suggest reading the pre-update part below first, then this part.**  Here's a synthesis of the problem, though:

> Basically, I have a collision detection and resolution engine with a
>   grid spatial partitioning system where order-of-collision and
>   collision groups matter. One body at a time must move, then detect
>   collision, then resolve collisions. If I move all the bodies at once,
>   then generate possible collision pairs, it is obviously faster, but
>   resolution breaks because order-of-collision isn't respected. If I
>   move one body a time, I'm forced to get bodies to check collisions,
>   and it becomes a n^2 problem. Put groups in the mix, and you can imagine why it gets very slow very fast with a lot of bodies.

---

**Update:** I've worked really hard on this, but couldn't manage to optimize anything.

[I successfully implemented the "painting" described by Will and changed groups into bitsets, but it is a very very minor speedup.](https://github.com/SuperV1234/SSVSCollision/commit/a03f0168722d0949a569844833fd098fda008bbb)

I also discovered a **big** issue: *my engine is order-of-collision dependent.*

[I tried an implementation of unique collision pair generation](https://github.com/SuperV1234/SSVSCollision/commit/be800f59fe985e50c04abbd6272e5223128b459a#L15L38), which definitely speed up everything by a lot, but broke the *order-of-collision*.

Let me explain:

- in my original design (not generating pairs), this happens:

  1. a single body moves
  2. after it has moved, it refreshes its cells and gets the bodies it collides against
  3. if it overlaps a body it needs to resolve against, resolve the collision

  this means that if a body moves, and hits a wall (or any other body), only the body that has moved will resolve its collision and the other body will be unaffected.

  **This is the behavior I desire**.

  I understand it's not common for physics engines, but it has a lot of advantages for *retro-style* games.
- in the usual grid design (generating unique pairs), this happens:

  1. **all** bodies move
  2. after **all** bodies have moved, refresh all cells
  3. generate unique collision pairs
  4. for each pair, handle collision detection and resolution

  in this case a simultaneous move could have resulted in two bodies overlapping, and they will resolve at the same time - this effectively makes the bodies "push one another around", and breaks collision stability with multiple bodies

  This behavior is common for physics engines, **but it is not acceptable in my case**.

I also found another issue, which is major (even if it's not likely to happen in a real-world situation):

- consider bodies of group A, B and W
- A collides and resolves against W and A
- B collides and resolves against W and B
- A does nothing against B
- B does nothing against A

there can be a situation where a lot of A bodies and B bodies occupy the same cell - in that case, there is a lot of unnecessary iteration between bodies that mustn't react to one another (or only detect collision but not resolve them).

For 100 bodies occupying the same cell, it's **100^100** iterations! This happens because unique pairs aren't being generated - but **I can't generate unique pairs**, otherwise I would get a behavior I do not desire.

**Is there a way to optimize this kind of collision engine?**

These are the guidelines that must be respected:

- Order of collision is **extremely important!**

  - Bodies must move **one at a time**, then check for collisions **one at a time**, and resolve after movement **one at a time**.
- Bodies must have 3 group bitsets

  - **Groups**: groups the body belongs to
  - **GroupsToCheck**: groups the body must **detect** collision against
  - **GroupsNoResolve**: groups the body must **not resolve** collision against
  - There can be situations where I only want a collision to be detected but not resolved

---

---

---

**Pre-update:**

***Foreword***: I'm aware that optimizing this bottleneck is not a necessity - the engine is already very fast. I, however, for fun and educational purposes, would love to find a way to make the engine even faster.

---

I'm creating a general-purpose C++ 2D collision detection/response engine, with an emphasis on flexibility and speed.

Here's a very basic diagram of its architecture:

[image: Basic engine architecture]

Basically, the main class is `World`, which owns (manages memory) of a `ResolverBase*`, a `SpatialBase*` and a `vector<Body*>`.

`SpatialBase` is a pure virtual class which deals with broad-phase collision detection.

`ResolverBase` is a pure virtual class which deals with collision resolution.

The bodies communicate to the `World::SpatialBase*` with `SpatialInfo` objects, owned by the bodies themselves.

---

There currenly is one spatial class: `Grid : SpatialBase`, which is a basic fixed 2D grid. It has it's own info class, `GridInfo : SpatialInfo`.

Here's how its architecture looks:

[image: Engine architecture with grid spatial]

The `Grid` class owns a 2D array of `Cell*`. The `Cell` class contains a collection of (not owned) `Body*`: a `vector<Body*>` which contains all the bodies that are in the cell.

`GridInfo` objects also contain non-owning pointers to the cells the body is in.

---

As I previously said, the engine is based on groups.

- `Body::getGroups()` returns a `std::bitset` of all the groups the body is part of.
- `Body::getGroupsToCheck()` returns a `std::bitset` of all the groups the body has to check collision against.

Bodies can occupy more than a single cell. GridInfo always stores non-owning pointers to the occupied cells.

---

After a single body moves, collision detection happens. I assume that all bodies are axis-aligned bounding boxes.

How broad-phase collision detection works:

**Part 1: spatial info update**

For each `Body` `body`:

1. - Top-leftmost occupied cell and bottom-rightmost occupied cells are calculated.
   - If they differ from the previous cells, `body.gridInfo.cells` is cleared, and filled with all the cells the body occupies (2D for loop from the top-leftmost cell to the bottom-rightmost cell).
2. `body` is now guaranteed to know what cells it occupies.

**Part 2: actual collision checks**

For each `Body` `body`:

- `body.gridInfo.handleCollisions` is called:

---

```
void GridInfo::handleCollisions(float mFrameTime)
{
    static int paint{-1};
    ++paint;

    for(const auto& c : cells)
        for(const auto& b : c->getBodies())
        {
            if(b->paint == paint) continue;
            base.handleCollision(mFrameTime, b);
            b->paint = paint;
        }
}
```

---

```
void Body::handleCollision(float mFrameTime, Body* mBody)
    {
        if(mBody == this || !mustCheck(*mBody) || !shape.isOverlapping(mBody->getShape())) return;

        auto intersection(getMinIntersection(shape, mBody->getShape()));

        onDetection({*mBody, mFrameTime, mBody->getUserData(), intersection});
        mBody->onDetection({*this, mFrameTime, userData, -intersection});

        if(!resolve || mustIgnoreResolution(*mBody)) return;
        bodiesToResolve.push_back(mBody);
    }
```

---

- Collision is then resolved for every body in `bodiesToResolve`.
- That's it.

---

So, I've been trying to optimize this broad-phase collision detection for quite a while now. Every time I try something else than the current architecture/setup, something doesn't go as planned or I make assumption about the simulation that later are proven to be false.

My question is: ***how can I optimize the broad-phase of my collision engine***?

Is there some kind of magic C++ optimization that can be applied here?

Can the architecture be redesigned in order to allow for more performance?

---

- Actual implementation: [SSVSCollsion](https://github.com/SuperV1234/SSVSCollision)
- [**Body.h**](https://github.com/SuperV1234/SSVSCollision/blob/master/include/SSVSCollision/Body/Body.h), [**Body.cpp**](https://github.com/SuperV1234/SSVSCollision/blob/master/src/SSVSCollision/Body/Body.cpp)
- [**World.h**](https://github.com/SuperV1234/SSVSCollision/blob/master/include/SSVSCollision/World/World.h), [**World.cpp**](https://github.com/SuperV1234/SSVSCollision/blob/master/src/SSVSCollision/World/World.cpp)
- [**Grid.h**](https://github.com/SuperV1234/SSVSCollision/blob/master/include/SSVSCollision/Spatial/Grid/Grid.h), [**Grid.cpp**](https://github.com/SuperV1234/SSVSCollision/blob/master/src/SSVSCollision/Spatial/Grid/Grid.cpp)
- [**Cell.h**](https://github.com/SuperV1234/SSVSCollision/blob/master/include/SSVSCollision/Spatial/Grid/Cell.h), [**Cell.cpp**](https://github.com/SuperV1234/SSVSCollision/blob/master/src/SSVSCollision/Spatial/Grid/Cell.cpp)
- [**GridInfo.h**](https://github.com/SuperV1234/SSVSCollision/blob/master/include/SSVSCollision/Spatial/Grid/GridInfo.h), [**GridInfo.cpp**](https://github.com/SuperV1234/SSVSCollision/blob/master/src/SSVSCollision/Spatial/Grid/GridInfo.cpp)

Callgrind output for latest version: http://txtup.co/rLJgz

Comment: Profile and identify bottlenecks. Let us know where they are, then we have something to work on.

Comment: @MaikSemder: I did that, and wrote it in the post. It's the only code snippet that's the bottleneck. Sorry if it's long and detailed, but that's part of the question because I'm sure that this bottleneck can only be solved by changing something in the design of the engine.

Comment: Sorry, was hard to find. Can you give us some numbers? The function time and number of objects processed in that function?

Comment: @MaikSemder: tested with Callgrind, on a binary compiled with Clang 3.4 SVN -O3: 10000 dynamic bodies - the function `getBodiesToCheck()` was called 5462334 times, and took 35,1% of the entire profiling time (Instruction read access time)

Comment: Nice, how often per frame, and average function time?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo You might find something in this question as well: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/57470/30949

Comment: i was wondering if the issue could not come from the stack bodiesToCheck. Because it allocates memory then copy all items each push -> O(n) within an O(n^2) loop, which makes O(n^3). You'd rather allocate once a possibly too big array then reduce the array size when you are done, so you're back in O(1) for push and O(n^2) for your loop.

Comment: @VincentPiel, I've changed some of the code since latest version. I've just updated the code snippets to reflect those changes. I don't allocate `bodiesToCheck` anymore.

Comment: no offense, but why exactly do you try to program a physics engine, is ode/buttet not enougth or do you just want to get a feel for it?

Comment: @Quonux: no offense taken. I just **love** "reinventing the wheel". I could take Bullet or Box2D and make a game with those libraries, but that's not really my goal. I feel much more fulfilled and learn much more by creating things from scratch and trying to overcome the obstacles that appear - even if that means being frustrated and asking for help. Other than my belief that coding from scratch is invaluable for learning purposes, I also find it a lot of fun, and a great pleasure to spend my free time on.

Comment: I've added a bit to my answer to explain how to half the number of checks while respecting the order of collisions.  Heaps are O(lg N).  The big speedup is from using this *and* using a hierarchical data-structure rather than the current grid.

Comment: Couldn't you check collisions without regard of the order and then "somehow" detect in what order they should have happened?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

***`getBodiesToCheck()`***

There could be two problems with the `getBodiesToCheck()` function; first:

```
if(!contains(bodiesToCheck, b)) bodiesToCheck.push_back(b);
```

This part is O(n<sup>2</sup>) isn't it?

Rather than checking to see if the body is already in the list, use *painting* instead.

```
loop_count++;
if(!loop_count) { // if loop_count can wrap,
    // you just need to iterate all bodies to reset it here
}
bodiesToCheck.clear();
for(const auto& q : queries)
    for(const auto& b : *q)
        if(b->paint != loop_count) {
            bodiesToCheck.push_back(b);
            b->paint = loop_count;
        }
return bodiesToCheck;
```

You are dereferencing the pointer in the gather phase, but you'd be dereferencing it in the test phase anyway so if you have enough L1 its no big deal.  You can improve performance by adding pre-fetch hints to the compiler too e.g. `__builtin_prefetch`, although that is easier with classic `for(int i=q->length; i-->0; )` loops and such.

That's a simple tweak, but my second thought is that there could be a faster way to organise this:

You can move to using **bitmaps** instead, though, and avoiding the whole `bodiesToCheck` vector.  Here's an approach:

You are using integer keys for bodies already, but then looking them up in maps and things and keeping around lists of them.  You can move to a slot allocator, which is basically just an array or vector.  E.g.:

```
class TBodyImpl {
   public:
       virtual ~TBodyImpl() {}
       virtual void onHit(int other) {}
       virtual ....
       const int slot;
   protected:
      TBodyImpl(int slot): slot(slot_) {}
};

struct TBodyBase {
    enum ... type;
    ...
    rect_t rect;
    TQuadTreeNode *quadTreeNode; // see below
    TBodyImpl* imp; // often null
};

std::vector<TBodyBase> bodies; // not pointers to them
```

What this means is that all the stuff needed to do the actual collisions is in linear cache-friendly memory, and you only go out to the implementation-specific bit and attach it to one of these slots if there's some need to.

To track the allocations in this vector of bodies you can use an array of integers as a [bitmap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap_index) and use [bit twiddling](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) or [`__builtin_ffs`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) etc.  This is super efficient to move to slots that are currently occupied, or find an unoccupied slot in the array.  You can even compact the array sometimes if it grows unreasonably large and then lots are marked deleted, by moving those on the end to fill in the gaps.

***only check for each collision once***

If you've checked if *a* collides with *b*, you don't need to check if *b* collides with *a* too.

It follows from using integer ids that you avoid these checks with a simple if-statement.  If the id of a potential collision is less-than-or-equal to the current id being checked for, it can be skipped!  This way, you'll only ever check each possible pairing once; that'll more than half the number of collision checks.

```
unsigned * bitmap;
int bitmap_len;
...

for(int i=0; i<bitmap_len; i++) {
  unsigned mask = bitmap[i];
  while(mask) {
      const int j = __builtin_ffs(mask);
      const int slot = i*sizeof(unsigned)*8+j;
      for(int neighbour: get_neighbours(slot))
          if(neighbour > slot)
              check_for_collision(slot,neighbour);
      mask >>= j;
  }
```

***respect the order of collisions***

Rather than evaluating a collision as soon as a pair is found, compute the distance to hit and store that in a [binary heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29).  These heaps are how you typically do priority queues in path-finding, so is very useful utility code.

Mark each node with a sequence number, so you can say:

- A<sup>10</sup> hits B<sup>12</sup> at 6
- A<sup>10</sup> hits C<sup>12</sup> at 3

Obviously after you've gathered all the collisions, you start popping them from the priority queue, soonest first.  So the first you get is A<sup>10</sup> hits C<sup>12</sup> at 3.  You increment each object's sequence number (the <sup>10</sup> bit), evaluate the collision, and compute their new paths, and store their new collisions in the same queue.  The new collision is A<sup>11</sup> hits B<sup>12</sup> at 7.  The queue now has:

- A<sup>10</sup> hits B<sup>12</sup> at 6
- A<sup>11</sup> hits B<sup>12</sup> at 7

Then you pop from the priority queue and its A<sup>10</sup> hits B<sup>12</sup> at 6.  But you see that A<sup>10</sup> is *stale*; A is currently at 11.  So you can discard this collision.

Its important not to bother trying to delete all stale collisions from the tree; removing from a heap is expensive.  Simply discard them when you pop them.

***the grid***

You should consider using a quadtree instead.  Its a very straightforward data-structure to implement.  Often you see implementations that store points but I prefer to store rects, and store the element in the node that contains it.  This means that to check collisions you only have to iterate over all bodies, and, for each, check it against those bodies in the same quad-tree node (using the sorting trick outlined above) and all those in parent quad-tree nodes.  The quad-tree is itself the possible-collision list.

Here's a simple Quadtree:

```
struct Object {
    Rect bounds;
    Point pos;
    Object * prev, * next;
    QuadTreeNode * parent;
};

struct QuadTreeNode {
    Rect bounds;
    Point centre;
    Object * staticObjects;
    Object * movableObjects;
    QuadTreeNode * parent; // null if root
    QuadTreeNode * children[4]; // null for unallocated children
};
```

We store the movable objects separately because we don't have to check if the static objects are going to collide with anything.

We are modeling all objects as axis-aligned bounding boxes (AABB) and we put them in the smallest QuadTreeNode that contains them.  When a QuadTreeNode a lot of children, you can subdivide it further (if those objects distribute themselves into the children nicely).

Each game tick, you need to recurse into the quadtree and compute the move - and collisions - of each movable object.  It has to be checked for collisions with:

- every static object in its node
- every movable object in its node that is before it (or after it; just pick a direction) in the movableObjects list
- every movable and static object in all parent nodes

This will generate all possible collisions, unordered.  You then do the moves.  You have to prioritise these moves by distance and 'who moves first' (which is your special requirement), and execute them in that order.  Use a heap for this.

You can optimise this quadtree template; you don't need to actually store the bounds and centre-point; that's entirely derivable when you walk the tree.  You don't need to check if a model is within the bounds, only check which side it is of the centre-point (a "axis of separation" test).

To model fast flying things like projectiles, rather than moving them each step or having a separate 'bullets' list that you always check, simply put them in the quadtree with the rect of their flight for some number of game steps.  This means that they move in the quadtree much more rarely, but you aren't checking bullets against far off walls, so its a good tradeoff.

Large static objects should be split into component parts; a large cube should have each face separately stored, for example.

Comment: "Painting" sounds good, I'll give it a try and report results as soon as possible. I don't understand the second part of your answer though - I'll try to read something about pre-fetching.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend QuadTree, it's more complicated than doing a grid, and if not done properly it will not work accurately and will create/remove nodes too often.

Comment: About your heap: is the **order of movement** respected?
Consider body **A** and body **B**. A moves to the right towards B, and and B moves to the right towards A. Now - when they collide simultaneously, the one that *moved first* should get *resolved first*, and the other one would be unaffected.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo if A moves towards B and B moves towards A in the same tick, and at the same speed, do they meet in the middle? Or does A, moving first, meet B where B starts?

Comment: @Will: the intended behavior is the second one. 1. A moves towards B; 2. A collides with B and **A**'s position gets resolved; 3. B moves, but since A has stopped right next to it, B shouldn't visibly move but only detect the collision and resolve its velocity

Comment: @VittorioRomeo and how many moving objects do you have?  I guess you are sure you want this behaviour, but surely it leads to objects seeming to pass through each other?  If you are comparing an object's path with the static position of all other objects, rather than their path, well...

Comment: @Will, tried with 10000 moving objects max. Performance is poor, but result is as expected. Stacks are "infinitely" stable. Object do not pass through each other. After A resolves against B, B will resolve against A - what I meant is that since A's resolution pushed "A right out of B", B's resolution won't change its position but will actually stop its velocity, because it's already hitting the edge of A (because A has already been resolved). If this isn't clear, let me know and I'll make an image.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo do you mean that if A moves first, and hits B, it stops wherever B was?

Comment: @Will: http://i.imgur.com/LOffq7Y.png

Comment: @VittorioRomeo you keep surprising me :)  Does it look ok in-game that distance travelled is truncated depending on this order-of-movement and where they happen to be at the beginning of each tick?  Got any videos of it in-game?  However, as it stands, ignore all I said and compute the hits for each object in strict move-first order, and adopt the octree instead of the grid.

Comment: @Will http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EExHVi8NMzA

Comment: That is very cool!  Well, looks like strict move-first order with an octree instead of a grid is perhaps a slight speedup.

Comment: I awarded you the bounty for all your efforts. I am still open to suggestion as I am not 100% satisfied with the current answers.

Answer (score 3):

I bet you just have a ton of cache misses when iterating over the bodies. Are you pooling all your bodies together using some data oriented design scheme? With an N^2 broadphase I can [simulate hundreds and hundreds](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b9-UC-sUU6U), while recording with fraps, of bodies without any framerate drops into the nether regions (less than 60), and this is all without a custom allocator. Just imagine what can be done with proper cache usage.

The clue is here:

```
const std::vector<Body *>
```

This immediately raises a huge red flag. Are you allocating these bodies with raw new calls? Is there a custom allocator in use? It's most important that you have all your bodies in a [huge array in which you traverse linearly](http://www.randygaul.net/2013/05/20/component-based-engine-design/). If traversing the memory linearly isn't something you feel you can implement consider using an intrusively linked list instead.

Additionally you seem to be using std::map. Do you know how the memory within std::map is allocated? You'll have an O( lg( N ) ) complexity for each map query, and this can likely be increased to O( 1 ) with a hash table. On top of this the memory allocated by std::map is going to thrash your cache horribly as well.

My solution is to use an intrusive hash table in place of std::map. A good example of both intrusively linked lists and intrusive hash tables is in Patrick Wyatt's base within his coho project: https://github.com/webcoyote/coho

So in short you'll probably need to create some custom tools for yourself, namely an allocator and some intrusive containers. This is the best I can do without profiling the code for myself.

Comment: "Are you allocating these bodies with raw new calls?" I'm not explicitly calling `new` when pushing bodies to the `getBodiesToCheck` vector - do you mean it is happening internally? Is there a way to prevent that while still having a dynamic-sized collection of bodies?

Comment: `std::map` is not a bottleneck - I also remember trying `dense_hash_set` and not gaining any kind of performance.

Comment: @Vittorio, then which part of _getBodiesToCheck_ is the bottleneck? We need information in order to help.

Comment: @MaikSemder: the profiler doesn't go deeper than the function itself. The whole function is the bottleneck, because it's being called once per frame per body. 10000 bodies = 10000 `getBodiesToCheck` calls per frame. I suspect the constant cleaning/pushing in the vector is the bottleneck of the function itself. The `contains` method is also part of the slowdown, but since `bodiesToCheck` never has more than 8-10 bodies in it, it should be that slow

Comment: @Vittorio would be nice if you put this info into the questions, thats a game-changer ;) Particularily I mean the part that getBodiesToCheck is called for _all_ bodies, so 10000 times each frame. I wonder, you said they were in groups, so why put them into the bodiesToCheck-array, if you already have the group information. You might elaborate on that part, looks like a very good optimization candidate to me.

Comment: @MaikSemder: I'll update the question now. - `bodiesToCheck` basically is (from the point of view of a body) "the vector of nearby bodies that are part of a group I have to check collision against". So, even if I know what groups I have to check collision against, I still to know what bodies from those groups are nearby.

Comment: @Vittorio Ah, I thought that is what a group is, the collectiuon of nearby bodies. That makes the problem clearer, you will need some kind of spatial hashing like octrees, BSPs or other acceleration structures. Please make it clearer in your question that you dont have it and remove all the noise from the qustion body. You might want to check the bullet sources for inspiration.

Comment: @MaikSemder I do have a spatial structure, it's a 2D grid. In fact, the question is all about the 2D grid spatial structure. Or am I missing the point here?

Comment: @Vittorio so you already have the "neighbour" information? A spatial structure is there to get this information quickly. So your grid knows all the bodies nearby already, then why adding them into arrays each frame?

Comment: @MaikSemder a body can occupy more than a single cell. Considering body A: A occupies more cells. A has to check every body in every cell it occupies. Some of these bodies can, themselves, occupy more cells (this is why A has to check for duplicates). In the end, A needs a collection of unique, nearby bodies of groups it needs to check collision against. That's why I need the `getBodiesToCheck` function. Hope I explained myself - let me know if something is not clear

Comment: @Vittorio That should be the point of the question. I would completely start a new question, this one already has too much noise. Focus on how to find/filter neighboring bodies quickly without looping through all of them.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9403/discussion-between-vittorio-romeo-and-maik-semder)

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the the count of bodies to check each frame:

Only check bodies that can actually move. Static objects only need to be assigned to your collision cells once after being created. Now only check collisions for groups which do contain at least one dynamic object. This should reduce the number of checks each frame.

Use a quadtree. See my detailed answer [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/10253/4345)

Remove all allocations from your physics code. You may wanna use a profiler for this. But I have only analysed memory allocation in C#, so I can't help with C++.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I see two problem candidates in your bottleneck function:

First is "contains" part - this is probably the main reason of bottleneck. It's iterating through already found bodies for every body. Maybe you should rather use some kind of hash_table / hash_map instead of vector. Then inserting should be faster (with searching of duplicities). But I don't know any specific numbers - I have no idea how many bodies are iterated here.

Second problem could be vector::clear and push_back. Clear may or may not evoke reallocation. But you may want to avoid it. Solution could be some flags array. But you may probably have a lot of objects, so it's memory ineffective to have list of all objects for every object. Some other approach could be nice, but I don't know what approach :/

Comment: About the first problem: I've tried using a dense_hash_set instead of the vector+contains, and it was slower. I tried filling the vector and then removing all duplicates, and it was slower.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I know nothing of C++, only Java, but you should be able to figure out the code. Physics is universal language right? I also realize this is a year old post, yet I just wanted to share this with everyone.

I have an observer pattern that basically, after the entity moves, it returns the object it has collided with, including a NULL object. Simply put:

(*I am remaking minecraft*)

```
public Block collided(){
   return World.getBlock(getLocation());
}
```

So say you are wandering around in your world. whenever you call `move(1)` you then call `collided()`. if you get the block you want, then perhaps particles fly and you can move left right and back but not forward.

Using this more generically than just minecraft as an example:

```
public Object collided(){
   return threeDarray[3][2][3];
}
```

Simply, have an array to point out the coordinates which, literally how Java does it, uses pointers.

Using this method still requires something other than a *priori* method of collision detection. You could loop this, but that defeats the purpose. You can apply this to Broad-, mid-, and narrow-collision techniques, but alone, its a beast especially when it works for 3D and 2D games quite well.

Now taking one more look, this means that, according to my minecraft collide() method, I will end up inside the block, so I will have to move the player outside of it. Instead of checking the player, I need to add a bounding box which checks which block is hitting each side of the box. Problem fixed.

the above paragraph may not be so easy with polygons if you want accuracy. For accuracy I would suggest defining a polygon bounding box that isn't a square, but not tesselated. if not, then a rectangle is just fine.